# How to configure postfix to accept Exchange Online or Exchange Online Protection emails?

Tags: postfix

how should I configure postfix so as it accepts emails from servers using multiple IP addresses (like Exchange Online and Exchange Online Protection)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I read: EOP (exchange online protection) and EO (exchange online) use multiple IP addresses to send email. My postfix configuration

```
reject_invalid_hostname
```

automatically hindered the communication between my postfix and EO (EOP) systems.
So I removed the reject_invalid_hostname form smtpd_recipient_restrictions in main.cf.
also I removed graylisting.

Thats all.